# Hyperlinks not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

I am having a hard time figuring out why a simple hyperlink is not working in my jsp.

Page file structure:
Web Content
->pages
->home.jsp, submit.jsp, review.jsp

in home.jsp:

```
<a href = "submit.jsp">Submit</a><br>
<a href = "review.jsp">Review</a>
```

What I get when I click either link:

Error 404--Not Found

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.

I have also tried with absolute urls:

```
<a href = "/page/submit.jsp">Submit</a>
```

I get the same result. It baffles me that a simple hyperlink is giving me so much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing all the three web pages directly under Web Content folder